# Estou com um problema na execução de uma repetição em C

Tags: c, funções, loop, for

Descrição da questão: *"Implemente a função abaixo que recebe uma string e a compacta, num único caractere, qualquer conjunto de caracteres repetidos consecutivos."*

> função:
> char *strpack(char *s)

> Exemplo de como ela deveria funcionar:

```
    strpack("Arrecadddaccao")           --> "Arecadacao"
    strpack("   AAAaaaBBB   CCCIALFFA") --> " AaB CIALFA""*
```

> Implementei a função abaixo:

```
char *strpack(char *s)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, tam = strlen(s);
//Analisa caractere por caractere
    for(i = 0; i <= tam; i = j)
    {
//Analisa a quantidade de caracteres repetidos
        for(j = i; j <= tam; j++)
        {
            if(s[i] != s[j])
            {
//Elimina os caracteres repetidos
                s[++i] = s[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return s;

Mas, por algum motivo, a repetição só é executada uma vez. Não consegui identificar o erro.
Qualquer contribuição é bem-vinda.
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

A repetição só é executada uma vez por causa do `break` dentro do `if`. Retirei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Como você tá trabalhando por passagem por referência então não precisa retornar a string na sua função, pois você já altera o conteúdo dela. Isso ocorre pois na passagem por referência passamos o endereço da variável/vetor e não uma cópia dela e por isso toda alteração feita é na variável/vetor que passamos como argumentos.
Então você pode deixar `void` como retorno.

Caso não goste de retornar `void` nas suas funções então você pode fazer uma validação de tamanho na sua string, isto é, se a string tiver tamanho 0 então retorne -1, caso contrário retorne 0. Ficaria assim:

```
int strpack(char *s)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, tam = strlen(s);
    if(tam == 0) return -1;
    //Analisa caractere por caractere
    for(i = 0; i <= tam; i = j)
    {
    //Analisa a quantidade de caracteres repetidos
        for(j = i; j <= tam; j++)
        {
            if(s[i] != s[j])
            {
                //Elimina os caracteres repetidos
                s[++i] = s[j];
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```